# Parse-Server NPM Install - Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, parse-server

I completed the Parse-Serve npm install as follows

```
$ npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
$ mongodb-runner start
$ parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY
```

when I tried to access it with the follow command.....

```
 $ curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppID123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

i got the following error:

```
{"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."}
```

Here is the result from running parse-server....

```
 $ parse-server --appId AppID123 --masterKey Master123

appId: AppID8Rasp
masterKey: ***REDACTED***
port: 1337
mountPath: /parse
maxUploadSize: 20mb
serverURL: http://localhost:1337/parse

parse-server running on http://localhost:1337/parse
warn: Unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames:  MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:311:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:254:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:158:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
warn: Unable to ensure uniqueness for user email addresses:  MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:311:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:254:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:158:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
error: Error generating response. { [MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' } name=MongoError, message=failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
error: Uncaught internal server error. { [MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' } MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:311:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:254:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:158:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:311:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:254:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:158:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

Sure could use some pointers !!    thanks.

Comment: The errors says that it cannot connect to the DB, so verify that the DB is running.

Comment: My apologies for being so thick, but how do I do that?

Comment: Tried;  sudo service parse-server status.  Says it's not running.  If it's not running, then jeeez, what up?  parse-server command seems to be working.....

Comment: can you please open a new tab in your terminal and execute the mongod command and try to run your server? (BTW - it will work only if you install mongodb)

Comment: Yes.  The original install instructions did not do an install of mongodb, I stopped all running applications and did a new install of mongodb-runner.  Started mongo-runner and parse-server again.  Still getting the same error when I try to post to parse-server (same internal server error)

Answer (score 0):

1) stop your server.

2) install mongodb

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

3) test to make sure it is running

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

A suitable response would be :

```
'mongod start/running, process 18777'
```

4) restart your server:

```
npm start
```

5) try creating the post again

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: AppID123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

p.s. "localhost" should really be the address of your server.

for a more detailed explanation : 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04